# Jena in-memory dataset seems to be slow when running SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, jena

I used `DatasetFactory.createTxnMem()` to create a in-memory dataset, then I loaded a RDF model into this dataset by using `setDefaultModel()`. The model has about 275K triples, and the SPARQL queries submitted to this dataset seems to be not as fast as we were hoping for (we expect this to be faster since it is an in-memory dataset).

Did we miss anything? for example, can we add an indexing system to this in-memory dataset?

Thanks for the help!

add the following query as an example:

```
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
    PREFIX hp: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_> 
    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
    PREFIX envo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ENVO_> 
    PREFIX stato: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/STATO_> 
    PREFIX ncit: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCIT_> 
    PREFIX pato: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_> 
    PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
    PREFIX uo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UO_> 
    PREFIX mi: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MI_> 
    PREFIX cogpo: <http://www.cogpo.org/ontologies/working/CogPOver2011.owl#COGPO_> 
    PREFIX exo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ExO_> 
    PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
    PREFIX omre: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ogms/OMRE_> 
    PREFIX ctxid: <http://purl.org/twc/ctxid/> 
    PREFIX geno: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GENO_> 
    PREFIX maxo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MAXO_> 
    PREFIX nbo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NBO_> 
    PREFIX hhear: <http://purl.org/twc/HHEAR_> 
    PREFIX omit: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OMIT_> 
    PREFIX uniprot: <http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/> 
    PREFIX pubchem: <http://rdf.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/compound/> 
    PREFIX symp: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/SYMP_> 
    PREFIX autism-core: <http://purl.org/autism-ontology/1.0/autism-core.owl#> 
    PREFIX cmo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CMO_> 
    PREFIX chebi: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_> 
    PREFIX vstoi: <http://hadatac.org/ont/vstoi#> 
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
    PREFIX doid: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_> 
    PREFIX cogat: <http://www.cognitiveatlas.org/ontology/cogat.owl#CAO_> 
    PREFIX hhear-kb: <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#> 
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
    PREFIX ogms: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OGMS_> 
    PREFIX aero: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/AERO_> 
    PREFIX oae: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OAE_> 
    PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
    PREFIX sio: <http://semanticscience.org/resource/> 
    PREFIX prov: <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> 
    PREFIX hasco: <http://hadatac.org/ont/hasco/> 
    PREFIX uberon: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_> 
    PREFIX oboInOwl: <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#> 
    PREFIX cl: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_> 
    PREFIX RID: <http://www.radlex.org/RID/#> 
    PREFIX efo: <http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_> 
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
    PREFIX obi: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_> 
    PREFIX fma: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FMA_> 
    PREFIX wikidata: <http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/> 
    PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/> 
    
SELECT ?ocType ?comment ?studyUri ?hasScopeUri ?hasRoleLabel ?hasVirtualColumnUri ?spaceScopeUri ?timeScopeUri ?lastCounter WHERE { 
    <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> a ?ocType . 
    <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:isMemberOf ?studyUri . 
    OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> rdfs:comment ?comment } . 
    OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:hasScope ?hasScopeUri } . 
    OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:hasReference ?hasVirtualColumnUri } . 
    OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:hasRoleLabel ?hasRoleLabel } . 
    OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:hasLastCounter ?lastCounter } . 
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of detail missing from this question that makes it impossible to answer as-is.  Faster compared to what?  Benchmarking methodology (did you account for cold-JVM and JIT effects)?  Example SPARQL queries and data snippets that demonstrate the performance?

Comment: Thanks @RobV! well, we use Blazegraph to hold our triples (275K of them), then we use Jena to do SPARQL queries by submitting the queries to blazegraph endpoint. Now, we created a in-mem model which mirrors the graph in blazegraph, and implemented the same queries against this in-memory graph. The performance remains pretty much the same - we were hoping to see a good improvement since we now have the model in memory instead of submitting the queries to another server. So that leads us to ask the question "is there a way to add some indexing system to this in-memory graph"?

Comment: why do you think there isn't any "index" used? Jena in-memory does make use of Java Maps, and there is at least some kind of index for spo, pos, osp, see https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/mem/GraphTripleStoreMem.java - such a small dataset could also be kept in-memory by Blazegraph I think. Moreover, query execution plans could be different depending on statistics used. You should also show some sample queries. And maybe also mention current execution times

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser! that is the key question we want to know - whether there is already some kind of index used for the in-memory dataset. We are just too lazy to read the source code I guess. This is an existing system, and we are not sure how the decision was made to host the graph in blazegraph, but using Jena to do the query. Let me post one sample query in my original question, because it is too big to fit in here.

Comment: thanks, so how long does this query take with Jena? I can see two triple patterns that can make use of `spo` index and then a bunch of `OPTIONAL` aka left-joins.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how much time the above query takes since a single request (a button click) from the front end triggers a few thousands queries like this (which all go to the blazegraph backend), and it takes about 8-9 seconds to get the response back. That is what we want to improve. Now, after we created an in-memory mirror of the same blazegraph graph, the same user request, still takes about 8 seconds, just a little bit improvement. So Jena does provide some indexing for the in-memory dataset?

Comment: The query shown isn't complete - it does not have a closing "}"" but may there is more in the query as well? Jena datasets are fully indexed. Are you loading the graph each time?

Comment: The query is complete (see my original question), and here is the last line of the query:

 `OPTIONAL { <http://hadatac.org/kb/hhear#SOC-2016-34-PSAMPLES> hasco:hasLastCounter ?lastCounter } .`

glad to know dataset created by using `DatasetFactory.createTxnMem()` and then `setDefaultModel(myModel)` is fully indexed! but if you create a `defaultModel` and then statement to it one by one, that simple `defaultModel` does not really have any index info, correct?

Comment: No closing `}` for WHERE.
Default model is indexed.
As you are issuing a few thousand queries in 8-9 seconds, maybe the time isn't all the query part.

Comment: thanks @AndyS! and you are in right, I missed the closing `}`. sorry about that! thanks for confirming the indexing part. that is the key question we wanted to know. We are in the middle of examining the logic to see where can we get more savings. thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. "a few" thousands? What happens in the the application? Also, to be honest I'm more impressed  y the speed. I mean, if we assume 2000 queries being "a few" and 8s total runtime, we have 8ms per query. Doesn't sound that slow to be fair. maybe it's possible to reduce the number of queries by using `VALUES` inline data?

Comment: Let me answer that question a little bit later, but for now, I found the problem, this line, `ResultSetRewindable resultsrw = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results)` is real slow, i.e., `copyResults()` is the problem. I am using Jena 3.0.1. Is there any way I can have some workaround to reach the same result?